# building custom installer

Tags: virtualbox, custom-installer

So i need some help with a project and I'm pretty novice to linux/ubuntu. I have a tool I have built for graphing and sorting the meaningful data from large binary and log files.

My problem is that part of the project is to build an installer for the tool to run on linux machines (I am able to assume the machine will be running ubuntu). I am doing everything for the graphing tool in python (not sure if that makes a difference or not).

My problem is I have never done anything like this before and have no idea where to start. I have done some research and google some tutorials but nothing is really helping and the documentation is hard to follow.
I have read up on using py2exe but im not sure if that is exactly what i would want to use. My end goal is to be able to email the installer to someone (or have it on a usb drive), have them run it that installed the dependencies needed to the graphing tool, then run they run program.

Im just looking for help taking the first step in the right direction if anyone knows of any good resources or would be able to walk me through the process of making this it would be a huge help! I have heard of a tool called autotools but I dont know much about it.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I am building everything on a macbook pro with ubuntu installed on virtualbox if that is of any importance.

Comment: Are you asking how to package and distribute the software you have created?

Comment: Yes, specifically for ubuntu distro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem two questions here:

1. How to *package* the new software so dependencies get installed
   too.
2. How to *distribute* the new software

These two problems are as old as computers and have been solved several different ways.

**The standard Debian/Ubuntu solution** is a *deb package* hosted in a Debian or Ubuntu *Repository*. There are other methods: Pip, PPAs, Snaps, github, etc. You will generally encounter the least trouble and find the most support with the standard deb/repo method.

**Creating a deb is not easy** - mostly because the creation process makes you ask a lot of questions that don't have easy answers: License, dependency versions, file locations, conflicts with other packages, etc. These questions ensure the widest compatibility with other packages, and prevent a lot of user problems. AskUbuntu is littered with unnecessary pleas because a packager cut corners.

An excellent place to start is the Ubuntu Packaging Guide http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html

**Plan for Updates** - you will probably need to release a new version of the package to address bugs and changed dependencies. The Ubuntu cycle of six-month is convenient for these updates.

**After you have created a package**, you can simply post it on a website (or github) or you can simply mail it to your peers. However, best practice is to contribute the software to Debian. Start that process at http://mentors.debian.net . The package will be merged into Ubuntu a few months before the next six-month release of Ubuntu.

**The big benefits** of using Debian and Ubuntu for distribution include discoverability in apt, testing and feedback by the community, community support for your package on sites like AskUbuntu, bug tracking in Launchpad, and convenient code storage and package maintenance tools in Alioth and Launchpad.